# Installing Visual Studio Tools for Office System

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, vsto, officedev

I have VS 2008 Standard and I'm trying to open a project that is a plug-in for Outlook, the project fails to load showing the message

> "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v9.0\Office
>   Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Office2007.targets was not
>   found".

The Office Tools directory is missing yet I have installed the Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies and the Visual Studio Tools for the Microsoft Office system 3.0.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) is not included with Visual Studio Standard (Source:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398242.aspx).  When you installed VSTO 3.0, you only installed the run-time components, which only lets you run published VSTO solutions, not design them in Visual Studio.

You will need to upgrade to either Visual Studio Team System or Visual Studio Professional.